# Annotating a TIKZ Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following diagram and I'd like to annotate and add some arrows but getting a little rotate-confused with the lines and text. I've attached the tikz code I'm working with below and an image with the lines and labels drawn in ..

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\offset}{0.05}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small,
declare function={gauss(\x,\y,\z)=\offset+1.2/(\y*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((\x- \z)^2)/(2*\y^2));}]

\begin{axis}[samples=101,smooth,hide axis,width=20cm,height=8cm]
\addplot [domain=-3:3] ({gauss(x,1,0)},x);
\addplot [domain=-3:3] ({1+gauss(x,1,0)},x);

\draw[-latex] (0,-3) --  (0,3) coordinate[pos=0.35](x1) coordinate[pos=0.5] (y1) node[below right,rotate=-90]{$X_k$};
\draw[-latex] (1,-3) -- (1,3) coordinate[pos=0.60](x2) coordinate[pos=0.5](y2) node[below right,rotate=-90]{$X_1$};
\addplot[-latex] coordinates{(-0.5,-4) (2,-4)};
\path (0,-4) coordinate (z1) (1,-4) coordinate (z2) (2,-4) coordinate (z3);

\coordinate (t0) at (-0.45,-4.1);
\coordinate (t) at (2,-4.1);
\coordinate (xi) at (-0.5,4);
\addplot[-latex] coordinates{(-0.5,-4.2) (-0.5,4)}; % yaxis
\end{axis}

\foreach \X in {1,2}
{
\draw ([xshift=-1mm]y\X) -- ([xshift=1mm]y\X);
\draw ([yshift=1mm]z\X) -- ([yshift=-1mm]z\X) node[below] {$t_\X$};
}

\node[anchor=north east] at (t) {time};
\node[anchor=north east] at (xi) {$X$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the lines inside `axis` and use these coordinates. I've also added `clips=false` to avoid problems with tip arrow draw below the axis.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\offset}{0.05}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small,
declare function={gauss(\x,\y,\z)=\offset+1.2/(\y*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((\x- \z)^2)/(2*\y^2));}]

\begin{axis}[samples=101,smooth,hide axis,width=20cm,height=8cm, clip=false]
\addplot [domain=-3:3] ({gauss(x,1,0)},x);
\addplot [domain=-3:3] ({1+gauss(x,1,0)},x);

\draw[-latex] (0,-3) --  (0,3) coordinate[pos=0.35](x1) coordinate[pos=0.5] (y1) node[below right,rotate=-90]{$X_k$};
\draw[-latex] (1,-3) -- (1,3) coordinate[pos=0.60](x2) coordinate[pos=0.5](y2) node[below right,rotate=-90]{$X_1$};
\addplot[-latex] coordinates{(-0.5,-4) (2,-4)};
\path (0,-4) coordinate (z1) (1,-4) coordinate (z2) (2,-4) coordinate (z3);

\coordinate (t0) at (-0.45,-4.1);
\coordinate (t) at (2,-4.1);
\coordinate (xi) at (-0.5,4);
\addplot[-latex] coordinates{(-0.5,-4.2) (-0.5,4)}; % yaxis

\draw[->, red] (-0.5,-5)--(0,-5) node[above,midway]{A};
\draw[->,red] (0,-1) node[left]{B}--({1+gauss(-1,1,0)},-1)node[below right]{C};
\end{axis}

\foreach \X in {1,2}
{
\draw ([xshift=-1mm]y\X) -- ([xshift=1mm]y\X);
\draw ([yshift=1mm]z\X) -- ([yshift=-1mm]z\X) node[below] {$t_\X$};
}

\node[anchor=north east] at (t) {time};
\node[anchor=north east] at (xi) {$X$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have the parametrizations of the Gaussians, so it is easy to define the points `B` and `C` as a function of some input parameter, which I call `\xp` here. And then you already export coordinates out of the axis, you could also do this for the arrow labelled `A`: just draw it outside of the axis. Then there is no need to switch off `clip`. (In the present setting, you could switch off `clip`, as [demonstrated by Ignasi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/461092/121799), but if you are to add more ingredients to your plot, this might not be the optimal way because often enough it is good to have pgfplots clip away auxiliary stuff.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\offset}{0.05}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xp}{-1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small,
declare function={gauss(\x,\y,\z)=\offset+1.2/(\y*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((\x- \z)^2)/(2*\y^2));}]

\begin{axis}[samples=101,smooth,hide axis,width=20cm,height=8cm]
\addplot [domain=-3:3] ({gauss(x,1,0)},x);
\addplot [domain=-3:3] ({1+gauss(x,1,0)},x);


\draw[-latex] (0,-3) --  (0,3) coordinate[pos=0.35](x1) coordinate[pos=0.5] (y1) node[below right,rotate=-90]{$X_k$};
\draw[-latex] (1,-3) -- (1,3) coordinate[pos=0.60](x2) coordinate[pos=0.5](y2) node[below right,rotate=-90]{$X_1$};
\addplot[-latex] coordinates{(-0.5,-4) (2,-4)};
\path (0,-4) coordinate (z1) (1,-4) coordinate (z2) (2,-4) coordinate (z3)
(-0.5,-5) coordinate (h1) (0,-5) coordinate (h2);

\coordinate (t0) at (-0.45,-4.1);
\coordinate (t) at (2,-4.1);
\coordinate (xi) at (-0.5,4);
\addplot[-latex] coordinates{(-0.5,-4.2) (-0.5,4)}; % yaxis
\coordinate (start) at (0,\xp);
\coordinate (end) at ({1+gauss(\xp,1,0)},\xp);
\end{axis}

\foreach \X in {1,2}
{
\draw ([xshift=-1mm]y\X) -- ([xshift=1mm]y\X);
\draw ([yshift=1mm]z\X) -- ([yshift=-1mm]z\X) node[below] {$t_\X$};
}

\draw[red,-latex] (start) node[left]{B} 
-- (end) node[below right]{C};
\draw[red,-latex] (h1) -- (h2) node[midway,above]{A};

\node[anchor=north east] at (t) {time};
\node[anchor=north east] at (xi) {$X$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is awesome thank you .. just one quick question if i want to add a second arrow/label below A that starts at the same position but ends at t2 how would i go about doing it? i keep getting an error when i try to duplicate A ..

Comment: nevermind got it has to add the coordinates as well - thanks again marmot and Ignasi !